# CSS selector to target a heading without any attribute

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this heading:

```
<h3>Contact info</h3>
```

Writing a class or a href to it it's not an option. It is in wordpress' user-edit.php file. I want to hide this element on the user's profile pages.

Is there any solution something like this?

```
h3["Contact info"] {
  display: none !important; visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: The h3 element don't have anything to target (as you can see). I specificly want to hide the Contact info, but I don't know how to target this with pure CSS. The only option is to hide every h3 on the profile page with css, than re-enable the new one's (I add classes to them) that I write in functions.php.

Comment: Without knowing the html structure of your page its difficult to help, but i'd probably experiment with :nth-child() Selectors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: What about targeting this tag as a child of it's parent? Do you know what this element parents are?

Comment: The problem is that I didn't wanted to hide every single h3 heading on the Wordpress profile page (all of the same level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nth-of-type pseudo class. Suppose the h3 you want to hide is the fourth h3 element under the parent h2 heading, and that h2 heading is the third h2 on the page (I'll assume you only have one h1 heading). Then you use:

```
h2:nth-of-type(2)  h3:nth-of-type(4) {...}
```

Just bear in mind that if you later add a new h3 heading before the one you are hiding, so changing the count, then you will have to change the number in the brackets.

But don't use display none and visibility:hidden together. Choose the one you actually want - display:none closes up the space the hidden element was taking, visibility hidden reserves the space even while hiding the element. They are contradictory. Also don't use !important unless you absolutely have to (see other StackOverflow answers as to why).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to can match an element based on a complete absence of attributes.

The closest you could come would be to test for the absence of some *specific* attributes.

```
h3:not([id]):not([class]) { }
```

Comment: I choosed another way: I hided every h3, and added a class to my new h3 fields. I didn't wanted to hide every wordpress original h3 headings on the profile page, but looks like there's no another option.

Answer (score 0):

if you only have one `h3`

```
h3{
  display: none !important;/* visibility: hidden;*/
}
```

---

otherwise you could use [attr selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) like h3[title~=yourTitle],

---

another option is to use child selectors

```
div > h3
```